# How to avoid scheduling/starting multiple runs of a Jenkins job at the same time

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

We are moving over our build system from Hudson to Jenkins and also to declarative pipelines in SCM. Alas, it looks like there are some hiccups. In Hudson, when a job was scheduled and waiting in the queue, no new jobs were scheduled for that project, which makes all the sense. In Jenkins, however, I observe there are e.g. 5 instances of a job started at the same time, triggered by various upstream or SCM change events. They have all even kind of started, one of them is actually running on the build node and the rest are waiting in  "Waiting for next available executor on (build node)". When the build node becomes available, they all dutifully start running in turn and all dutifully run through, most of them without no purpose at all as there are no more changes, and this all takes a huge amount of time.

The declarative pipeline script in SCM starts with the node declaration:

```
pipeline {

    agent {
        label 'BuildWin6'
    }
    ...
```

I guess the actual problem is that Jenkins starts to run these jobs even though the specified build node is busy. Maybe it thinks I might have changed the Jenkinsfile in the SCM and specified another build node to run the thing on? Anyway, how to avoid this? This is probably something obvious as googling does not reveal any similar complaints.

Comment: Found the same complaint at https://groups.google.com/g/jenkinsci-users/c/yrLm1j-aE88 , but there were no solutions. Our builds take about 30 minutes each, so we definitely don't want to run a separate build for each svn commit.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, answering myself. It looks like the best solution is to define another trigger job which is triggered itself by SCM changes. It should do nothing else, only checks out the needed svn repos (with depthOption: 'empty' for space and speed). The job needs to be bound to run on the same agent than the main job.

The main job is triggered only by the first job, not by SCM changes. Now if the main job is building for an hour, and there are 10 svn commits during that time, Jenkins will schedule 10 trigger job builds to run. They are all waiting in the queue as the agent is busy. When the agent becomes available, they all run quickly through and trigger the main job. The main job is triggered only once, for that one must ensure its grace/quiet period is larger than the trigger job run time.

Answer (score 0):

Our solution was to have the first step check for a trigger file and then create it when not found and execute the main task(s), else bail. Then the final step in the flow removes the trigger file.

The extra benefit here being that, should the flow fail mid-way, it cannot be restarted without intervention (i.e. removing the file, or setting a jenkins parameter that routes the pipeline to ignore it) meaning someone acknowledges the failure.